# How to hide "Created new window in existing browser session" in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hello I'm working on a project for university and I'm a newbie in bash scripting. Part of my code is the following (opens tabs in chromium):

```
chromium-browser& &>/dev/null
while read line
    do
        chromium-browser "$line"& &>/dev/null 
        sleep 5
    done < url.in
```

However, every time a tab opens I get an annoying message on the shell "Created new window in existing browser session". It doesn't stop the execution or anything, but I don't want it there, because I want the output afterwards to be clearer. Any ideas of how to make it disappear, since the redirecting didn't work?

Comment: Redirect stderr as well

Comment: @123 I changed &> to 2>, but nothing changed. Anyway, I think &> works for redirecting both stdout and stderr, doesn't it?

Comment: yeah sorry missed that, read it as a single `&` for background. You could try redirecting the entire loop although it should definitely be blocking the output the way you are doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nohup`:

```
nohup command >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working! Could you please explain why exactly? I tried man nohup, but couldn't get why it solved the problem...

Comment: `nohup` redirects all output to a file instead of showing it. You will have a `nohup.out` file in your folder now.

Comment: Just noticed! Thanks!

Comment: **nohup** ignores hangup signals and redirects output to **nohup.out** file. But as far as i know nohup output can be redirected to **/dev/null**

Answer (score 1):

Redirect both stdout and stderr to /dev/null, like this:

```
command > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

or

```
command &> /dev/null &
```

On the argument: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: Still nothing. The message is not an error by the way. It's something like information message. Because of that, I tried just 1>/dev/null, but still no luck.

Comment: My bad, that's because it's in background. I tested it without the `&`. Put the `&` and the end of the command, see my updated answer.